# Leave one out encoding with Dask dataframes

Tags: python, dask, leave-one-out

I have the following dask `dataframe`:-

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5], "B": ["a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "b", "b", "a", "c"], "y":[0, 10, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 12, 11]})
X = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

In the `dataframe` `X`, column `B` has the categories that I want encode, and column `y` are the `y` values. This is just an example `dataframe`. In reality, my dataset has more than 1000 categories.

How can I do leave-one-out encoding on a `dask` `dataframe`?

Thanks in advance.